# 张九龄《感遇》“奈何阻重深”句解／Translation of a sentence in one of Zhang Jiuling's poems

Tags: poetry, literary-chinese

张九龄《感遇》之一首：

> 江南有丹橘，经冬犹绿林。 岂伊地气暖？自有岁寒心。 可以荐嘉客，奈何阻重深。 运命惟所遇，循环不可寻。 徒言树桃李，此木岂无阴？

请问其中“奈何阻重深”一句怎么讲？“重”应读阳平还是去声？

此诗作者借歌颂丹橘以表自己遭排挤的愤懑心情，表达自己的坚贞不屈。“可以荐嘉客”句“荐”作“赠送”解。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“可以荐嘉客，奈何阻重深”。这句在说，这个水果是很给朋友们的一件很好的礼品，但无奈路途遥远，不方便。隐含着诗人当前所处的位置远离曾经工作和生活的地方而表现出一种悲伤的心情。“阻重深”，表示路途险阻，“重” chong 一般用在强制“很多的”的情况下，表示有很多的东西（通常都用在表示有困难）包围着我们，在这里强调很困难，比如“需要克服重重险阻，被围困的军队需要突破重重包围圈”。“奈何”表示口语中都是用“无奈”，表示没有办法或很难解决问题。

另外，在诗词和歌曲中，我们经常把一些并列式的词汇颠倒过来，比如“运命”平时都写成“命运”。

Answer (score 3):

"重"，应该读chóng 即阳平(2声)

"江南有丹橘，经冬犹绿林。"

> 江南一带生长着一种奇异的丹橘，经历严冬橘林依然枝叶苍翠，郁郁青青。

"岂伊地气暖，自有岁寒心。"

> 难道这是因为那里地气和暖使然？原来是这种橘树自有凌寒傲霜的本性。

"可以荐嘉客，奈何阻重深。"

> 款待贵宾与亲朋，这丹橘作为上好的水果当之无愧，怎奈一路上山高水深，运送它交通不便。

"徒言树桃李，此木岂无阴？"

> 世人都喜欢栽种桃李，其实这丹橘的果实不但可以款待宾客，而且四季长青，终年绿荫葱茏，哪一点不如桃李呢？

本诗以橘喻人，诗人借赞颂丹橘，经冬犹绿，是因为有耐寒的本性来比喻自己也有贤人一样的高尚品质，但不被人识，只能抑郁不平。全诗平淡自然，语言温雅醇厚，设喻贴切，抒发胸臆圆转自如，愤怒哀伤不露痕迹，给读者留下了回味与想像的空间，故历来为人称颂。